# listing of directory with many files

Tags: list, file, ls

In ubuntu I have a folder that contains many (~10M) .txt files (around 1-2KB each). Folder is not big by itsself (around 400MB) and does not contain subfolders, just the .txt files. 
I need to list it and do not succeed in doing so. (i can count the number of files,though, with wc -l)
question is: is there a way to split the folder somehow or other way, without calling methods that ls uses?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the output of `ls` command in a file.

```
ls -m > list.txt
```

Comment: thanks, issue is that I have to split the folder somehow because I want to transfer it via ftp. ftp fails (filezilla) because listing does not respond within a logical time